# Download video from url in java

Tags: java, video, stream

```
  private void downloadVideo(String videoUrl, String destinationPath) throws IOException {

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(videoUrl);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            byte[] videoBytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());

            File destinationFile = new File(destinationPath);
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(destinationFile, videoBytes);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Failed to download video. HTTP status code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
    }
```

I am using this code to download a public videoUrl and saving it to a disk. But the issue is the save video does not play and the size of the saved video seems pretty small as well.

So, the question is how to download Mp4 video from a public video link in a playable format?

Comment: Please give a problematic URL

Comment: It looks like you might be using some third-party libraries you're not mentioning, which would make reproducing and resolving this problematic.  I see the following classes which aren't part of core Java: `CloseableHttpClient`, `HttpClients`, `HttpGet`, `HttpResponse`, `EntityUtils`, `FileUtils`.  Please list the library(ies) you're using so that you can be helped.

Comment: It must be said there are now few web pages in existence that will allow direct access to static files without the involvement of scripting, so unless you have a library that supports it, you're unlikely to be lucky enough to get it directly like that

Comment: The issue was in the URL basically, it was downloading an html and from that html i had to extract the actual video URL